Getting exception even after the operation was done inside async function
I have written an async function which updates a dynamo-db table attribute value and here's my code snippet
public async Task UpdateCount()
{
    try
    {
        await _dynamoDbService.UpdateItemAsync(new UpdateItemRequest
            {
                TableName = _ledgerSummaryTableName,
                ExpressionAttributeNames = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "#inv", "InvAttr"}, {"#Count", "DetCount"} },
                ExpressionAttributeValues =
                    new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> { { ":InvDetCount", new AttributeValue { N = "200" } }},
                UpdateExpression = "SET #inv.#Count = :InvDetCount",
                Key = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
                {
                    {"SubsId", new AttributeValue {S = "12345" },
                    {"ItemId", new AttributeValue {S = "1_98765"} }
                }
            });
    }
    catch (AmazonServiceException exception)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"Error: UpdateInvoiceDetailCount operation failed for IndexedLedgerSummary table. " + $"{exception.Message}");

        throw new AuthenticationException(new Fault
        {
            Code = AccountErrorCode.UpdateLedgerSummaryItemFailed,
            Message = "UpdateInvoiceDetailCount operation failed for IndexedLedgerSummary table. "
        }, exception);
    }
}

The expectation from the above code is, it will update the attribute DetCount with the desired value. I'm facing a scenario where the update is happening on the attribute (I see the new value updated) but still the function end of throwing the error that's there in the catch block.
Can anyone help in understanding what am I missing here?
The exception that I'm getting is - The document path provided in the update expression is invalid for update
When I checked related to this error in aws documents, it says the error is thrown when the table doesn't have this attribute to update. But post getting this error when I check the table, I see the attribute having correct value updated

That means that the implementation of UpdateItemAsync sets the value and then throws an exception. Technically I see nothing in this code that would cause that side-effect. You should investigate the details of the thrown exception and maybe you can share that details in your question.

What does the exception state?

@LeeroyHannigan Exception is - UpdateInvoiceDetailCount operation failed for IndexedLedgerSummary table.The document path provided in the update expression is invalid for update

Unrelated: MS recommends to not use string interpolation in logging message templates.

and is the exception type deriving from: AmazonServiceException ?

Yes @IvanPetrov


The document path provided in the update expression is invalid for update

This exception means that you tried to update a JSON path without its root existing.
This means that InvAttr doesn't exist on the item your updating, leading to failure.

But how is it updating the DetCount then? I see it's getting updated correctly even though I get the exception

It won't update with that exception. If you get a non 200 code, the update will not happen. You may have an insert somewhere else in your code path.
